# Simulating operator like "inverse of ??"

Tags: c#, operators

`a ?? b`

- If `a` is not `null` => returns `a`.
- Else (`a` is `null`) => returns `b`.

I want to simulate something like its inverse (AFAIK there is no operator to do this):

- If `a` is `null` => return `a`.
- Else (`a` is not `null`) => returns `b`.

The idea is that `b` would be the result of a function that receives `a` and needs to avoid `null` parameters. Like this: `a XX fn(a)` where XX would be the operator (if it exists).

My only two variants are:

- `a == null ? a : fn(a)`
- `a == null ? null : fn(a)`

Is there any way to simplify this code?

Comment: Isn't it easier to let the method fn check the argument for null?

Comment: What's the type of `fn(a)`?

Comment: Well, you can’t add new operators to the language, so what is the point?

Comment: The two lines you have are pretty simple.  Why do you think you need something even simpler than what you have?  Do you do this so often that you think it's really worth having an operator just for this?  You can make a method that does this if you really do it that much.

Comment: @Neil does the type changes anything?

Comment: I myself find "a == null ? a : fn(a)" really simple (and readable!). There is no operator for what you want to do (as far as I know), and you can't add new operators.

Comment: @JensGranlund It's not my function, I can't modify it.

Comment: Then wrap the function in your own function.  Personaly I would use `if(a != null) { a = fn(a);}`

Comment: Its true that it is readable. I didn't find it very simply (or maybe an accurate word would be nice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish? Something like this?

```
TResult NullFn<TParam, TResult>(TParam a, Func<TParam, TResult> method)
{
if(a == null) return null;
return method(a);
}

...

var result = NullFn(a, a => fn(a))
```

But the best solution IMHO would be to just have `fn` return null if it is passed a null value.

EDIT:

The method at the top is only an example. You might want to use something like this in a situation where you've got a LOT of the same operation over and over again in a specific area and you can't change fn because it would make is easier to focus on the rest of the code and there's a chance you might want to alter the null-handling behavior for all your operations at once in the future. (I'm assuming that is the case because you're asking in the first place.) But I wouldn't use this across an entire application because it isn't clear what's happening if you don't have the `NullFn` function right in front of you.

Comment: You could probably make the `object` a generic type as well there.

Comment: The code is just an example that I don't recommend actually using. The real solution I'd suggest is to add the condition to the method `fn`. Adding the NullFn method will be very confusing to anybody who comes along in the future.

Comment: True, it was rather meant as a general note anyway :)

Comment: I'll add it anyway, I was thinking when I wrote the method that making the result type generic would prevent the type from being inferred from usage without have to explicitly write it each time, but that's not actually true.

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with simple condition?

```
if (a != null) b = fn(a);
```

Another option - add a condition to your method:

```
public B fn(A a)
{
    if (a == null)
        return null;

    return new B();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would prefer

```
(a != null) ? fn(a) : null
```

because I think it makes the intention more obvious, but I can not think of a way to simplify that much. You could use an extension method if you like.

```
a.CallIfNotNull(fn)
```

with the following extension method

```
internal static T CallIfNotNull<T>(this T value, Func<T, T> function)
    where T : class
{
    return (value != null) ? function(value) : null;
}
```

Not really better but probably less error prone and easier to type given IntelliSense.

(Is assumed the function returns a value of the same type as the argument as the question suggests.)

Comment: From the name I would rather expect it to be `fn.CallIfNotNull(a)`.

Comment: I also thought about that but was unsure if you can easily invoke an extension method on a method group - I don't think so - or if you have to assign the method to a delegate type variable first making the call site quite ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `T a;` and `T fn(T a);` using the same user-defined type T, then you can write `a && fn(a)` and it will expand to `T.False(a) ? a : T.&(a, fn(a))`.

Comment: This is a really clever idea...but unfortunately yields cryptic code.

Comment: @DanielBrückner Well, perhaps not so cryptic to users of Python, JavaScript, Perl etc?

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question with the ?: implementations at the bottom.

The only improvement i would suggest is to wrap the functionality in a method that makes it cleaner and less error prone to do.

```
object SafeB(object a)
{
    return a==null ? a : b(a);
}
```

The compiler will probably inline this so you won't lose performance.

You may even be able to implement it as an extension method of the class that provides b so that it becomes an even more integrated solution.